# Search for values in two columns and match it with third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A, Column B and Column C have some numbers. I want to test if values of either A or B are present in C. If yes, then display yes, else no. Please let me know an easy excel formula for this

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ben but I am unable to get the correct answer still. A and B have receipt numbers. C also has a receipt number. I want to check if either A or B are present in C. If either A or B is present, then show yes. Otherwise No. Have been getting really crazy over this for a few days.

Comment: Can I share the file with you somehow? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I have added a screenshot. hope it is better now.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(P:P,X2)+COUNTIF(P:P,Y2)>0,"yes","no")`. Or maybe `=IF(COUNTIF(P:P,"*"&X2&"*")+COUNTIF(P:P,"*"&Y2&"*")>0,"yes","no")`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by doing using the formula below

```
=IF(OR(IF(COUNTIF($P:$P,X1)>0,1,0),IF(COUNTIF($P:$P,Y1)>0,1,0)),"YES","NO")
```

Below is a sample data and result also

[image: Sample data and result]

Comment: You've got it backwards: check if the values in X or Y are in P.